# Can I perform commands on multiple tables with specific values in SQL Server without using identical WHERE clauses each time?

Tags: sql-server

I have a large number of operations I want to perform on database tables that meet a particular condition for a shared column name, and am wondering if this can be done without repetitive use of WHERE.

Say I've got these two tables and I want to make changes only to rows with General values of 2.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    General int,
    Specific int)

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    General int,
    Specific int)

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)
```

Obviously I can do this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Specific = Specific + 1
WHERE General = 2

UPDATE table2
SET Specific = Specific - 1
WHERE General = 2
```

But is there a way I can do this without having "WHERE General = 2" each time? I thought I might be able to do this:

```
WITH 
table1_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE General = 2
),
table2_CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE General = 2
)

UPDATE table1_CTE
SET Specific = Specific + 1

UPDATE table2_CTE
SET Specific = Specific - 1;
```

But "WITH" it seems is only for single commands.

Comment: Often, if you find yourself wanting to treat multiple tables identically it's a sign that they should have been a single table all the time. What should have been data in additional column(s) has instead been modelled as part of the table names.

Comment: As far as I am aware this is impossible in any SQL database. Simply because updates (and inserts) are against a single target table. Therefore doing the same / different updates over two tables is not possible in a single statement. However this is a perfect example for using transactions to ensure that all or no tables are done.

Comment: You *could* use a **simple** `VIEW` which is filtered to where `General` have the value `2`; then when you perform an `UPDATE` against that `VIEW` it only `UPDATE`s the rows in that `VIEW`. Of course, this is a pointless idea if `General` needs to be parametrised. Then, perhaps, you are better off with a stored procedure with parametrised `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: @Larnu - the UPDATE to the view will fail if it affects more than one target table

Comment: That wouldn't be a **simple** `VIEW` anymore though, @MartinSmith .

Comment: "Simple" is quite an ambiguous term and in the eye of the beholder!

Comment: [Updatable View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updatable-views) for specifics.

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL. Not ideal but will do the work.